# Combine multiple rows in R based on Column A

Tags: r, csv, text, dplyr

I am working on summarizing a huge dataframe with over 7000 non-number values inside of it.

Below is an example of what I am trying to do with the data.

| Person | Description | Initials | Locations |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jake | Info1 | JK | Mars |
| Jake | Info2 | JK | Jupiter |
| Sam | Info1 | SP | Saturn |
| Sam | Info2 | SP | Earth |
| Sam | Info3 | SP | Mars |

I hope my output is something like this:

| Person | Description | Initials | Locations |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jake | Info1 ; Info2 | JK | Mars ; Jupiter |
| Sam | Info1 ; Info2 ; Info3 | SP | Saturn ; Earth ; Mars |

I have imported my data into R, but not too sure on how to proceed with combining all the data based on the first column. I know with numbers we can use aggregate in R. How should I go about with just values/non-number information and combining it them with semi-colons in between each of them.

I will appreciate any help with this. Thank you in advance.

`test <- read.table(file='test_data.tsv', sep = '\t', header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use summarise and paste and collapse :

```r
test <- read.table(
text = "Person  Description Initials    Locations
Jake    Info1   JK  Mars
Jake    Info2   JK  Jupiter
Sam Info1   SP  Saturn
Sam Info2   SP  Earth
Sam Info3   SP  Mars", sep = '\t', header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)

library(tidyverse)

test %>%
  group_by(Person, Initials) %>%
  summarise(Description = paste(Description, collapse = ","),
            Locations = paste(Locations, collapse = ","))
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'Person' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Groups:   Person [2]
#>   Person Initials Description       Locations        
#>   <chr>  <chr>    <chr>             <chr>            
#> 1 Jake   JK       Info1,Info2       Mars,Jupiter     
#> 2 Sam    SP       Info1,Info2,Info3 Saturn,Earth,Mars
```

But beware, you're basically making your data "untidy" ...

Comment: Thank you so much! This method works perfectly. I totally forgot about tiddyverse. I appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aggregate()`:

The variables on the rhs of `~` are the grouping variables while the `.` represents all other variables in the 'test' data frame. The other passed arguments `paste()` and `collapse` are then used on the grouped data.

```r
aggregate(.~Person+Initials, test, paste, collapse=" ; ")
##   Person Initials           Description             Locations
## 1   Jake       JK         Info1 ; Info2        Mars ; Jupiter
## 2    Sam       SP Info1 ; Info2 ; Info3 Saturn ; Earth ; Mars
```

It yields the identical result as the other proposed solution:

```r
res_Tjebo <- test %>%
                group_by(Person, Initials) %>%
                summarise(Description = paste(Description, collapse = ","),
                          Locations   = paste(Locations,   collapse = ",")) %>% 
                ungroup()

res_jwarz <- test %>% 
                aggregate(
                  .~Person+Initials, 
                  ., 
                  paste, collapse=",") %>%
                as_tibble()

identical(res_Tjebo, res_jwarz)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you  for the help.  Unfortunately this method yields the numeral length for the pasted cells instead of the actual text information.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but I am glad you have found a working solution :).